# How to determine what capabilities are blocking an app from installing

Tags: google-play-store, installation, permissions

My bank has an app for Android phones, but that same app won't install on my tablet.  Is there a way to determine what capability or permission is blocking it from even being listed in the Play store?

Comment: Hard without knowing the details. Could be the Android version, screen resolution, or one of many other things. Easiest way would be to contact the developer *with your device details*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm hoping to find a generic way - go to the app page and have something other than "this app is incompatible with your device" listed - perhaps a reason would be nice there.

Comment: This you have to deal with Google itself, to extend its message to "this app is incompatible with your device *because...*". Until then, the "generic way" is to ask the developer (who should know what he put into the app's Manifest) -- or get a copy of the `*.apk` and check the Manifest yourself. Sorry, but I see no other way.